# Jenkins Content Security Policy

Tags: html, css, jenkins, content-security-policy

I'm confused about Jenkins Content Security Policy.

I know these sites:

- [Configuring Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy)
- [Content Security Policy Reference](http://content-security-policy.com/)

I have a html page shown via Jenkins Clover Plugin. This html page uses inline style, e.g.:

```
<div class='greenbar' style='width:58px'>
```

The div-element visualizes a progressbar.
Using the default Jenkins CSP configuration leads to the following result:
[Progressbar_FAIL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jr1h.png)

The result i want to have looks like this:
[Progressbar_WORKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cXuv.png)

I tried to relax the CSP rules, adding different combinations of parameters (script-src, style-src) with different levels (self, unsafe-inline,..) but nothing works.

So my questions for now:

1. Where do i have to specify the CSP configuration?
2. Is it possible to use inline styles?
3. Where should the styles be located? My css-stylesheets are located local on the Jenkins Server.
4. What is the best way to get inline style and CSP rules "satisfied"

**Update**

**1. Try:**
`-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'` 
in the jenkins.xml file. Then the following error occurs:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

**2. Try**
`-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'` in the jenkins.xml file. Then the following error occurs:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution

I understand that this try can not solve my problem, because default-src includes style-src

**3. Try**
`-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'` in the jenkins.xml file. Then the following error occurs:

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   s://jenkins/andsomedir/stylesheet.css [its https://... not allowed to post more than two links :(]
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'unsafe-inline'".

Comment: It is possible to use inline styles or styles from files located on the Jenkins server. It sounds like you're on the right track, but you haven't posted *exactly* what you tried (did you use the Script Console? what did you type? what values did you set the CSP parameter to?), so it's hard to point out what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Updated my post.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While experimenting, I recommend using the Script Console to adjust the CSP parameter dynamically as described on the [Configuring Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) page. (There's another note in the Jenkins wiki page that indicates you may need to Force Reload the page to see the new settings.)

In order to use both inline styles and local stylesheets, you need to add both *self* and *unsafe-inline*:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

Depending on how the progressbar is manipulated, you may need to adjust 'script-src' in the same way as well.

Once you find a setting that works, you can adjust the Jenkins startup script to add the CSP parameter definition.

Comment: If you're unsure how to apply these settings permanently (since changes via Script Console are discarded after Jenkins reboot), you can append them to the JAVA_ARGS in `/etc/default/jenkins`:

`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';\""`

Comment: I had to clean up the browser cache after changing the policy to be reflected.

Comment: Another way to apply this upon startup is to use https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script.   Create a file, such as ~jenkins/init.groovy.d/adjust-content-security-policy.groovy with the single line of System.setProperty(...) and it will be executed after Jenkins has started.

Comment: Removing 'CSP' header itself by firing below command , System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")                                 will this work ? I know that this will make jenkins volatile , but I don't bother about it as of now .

Comment: I find the proposal from @hshib is the most elegant and less intrusive. it works like a charm. The JAVA_ARGS approach didn't work for me anyway.

Answer (score 25):

Just to be clear about setting this CSP property permanently on Jenkins.

If you are running Jenkins on **Ubuntu**:

1. `$ vim /etc/default/jenkins`
2. Find the line with `JAVA_ARGS` and add the CSP policy like this: `JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src data:;\""`

If you are running Jenkins on **CentOS**:

1. `$ vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins`
2. Find the line with `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS` and add the CSP policy like this: `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src data:;\""`

Save the file and restart Jenkins.
`$ sudo service jenkins restart` or in your browser `http://localhost:8080/safeRestart`

Comment: Can you help me to set it permanently in windows. I'm not sure which file i have to select

Comment: The default location in Windows is `C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.xml`. Please check.

Answer (score 5):

Below properties worked for me. The following properties allow all the external servers.

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';")
```

Comment: That pretty much disables CSP completely, you might just use "": https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Comment: The other options did not work out for me, this did. But I would not recommend doing this, as it opens a lot of gates.

Comment: @user158037, somehow "" it didn't work for me

Comment: @kolukuri try: `System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")`

Answer (score 4):

In examples below I set
`CSP="default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';"`, which was enough for my test reports to be rendered correctly, but you can specify your own policy. Here is an example for Snyk reports:

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; img-src \"*\" data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';\" \
```

---

#### Jenkins CSP override for systemd

```bash
cat <<-'EOF' > /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true \
    -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';\""
EOF

# Restart Jenkins
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart jenkins
```

---

#### Jenkins CSP override for system V

```bash
# Use correct config file:
# - Red Hat: /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
# - Debian: /etc/default/jenkins
cat <<-'EOF' >> /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true \
    -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';\""

# Restart Jenkins
service jenkins restart
```

Comment: This is the accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

To add more to the @Kirill's answer ...

If jenkins is deployed in `tomcat` container, set the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment value in `setenv.sh file` ( Present in `${CATALINA_BASE}/bin` Folder ) as highlighted below:-

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxNewSize=768m -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${CATALINA_BASE}/logs/java.hprof -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"\"
```

or

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -XX:MaxNewSize=768m -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/software/jenkins/tomcat_jenkins/logs/java.hprof -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:-UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src *; 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src *; 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *;\
```

After Changing the above file, restart the `tomcat`. It worked like charm to me. Hope it helps :)

Note:- CSP is only applicable for the plugins like HTML publisher, maven plugin . It didn't work for email html file.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to share my procedures I always follow one of theseworkarounds. However you need to pay attention to your security constraints since applying these fixes would be potentially insecure.

1. Temporal fix:

Go to Jenkins console and applythe following commands depending on the kind of CSP policies relaxation that you want.

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline';")
```

This workaround is aimed for temporal tests or dev environment.

If you want to change it permanently add this to the java command when you run the application:

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

Finally I strongly suggest you to read these articles:

Official Jenkins documentation
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Workarounds to reset CSP rules temporary or permanently:
https://www.cyotek.com/blog/adjusting-the-jenkins-content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue. The below solution worked for me.

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-scripts allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox; style-src 'unsafe-inline' *;" -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=TLSv1 -jar C:/server/Jenkins.war --httpPort=8280
```

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to ***Jenkins 2.346.1***, the "JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS" variable  had no effect on the Jenkins [CSP](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/) (I wonder why), so I renamed it to "***JAVA_OPTS***", and it is working again.

This is the value I use for JAVA_OPTS within Jenkins [Kubernetes-Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin):

```
-Dpermissive-script-security.enabled=true 
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-scripts;
 default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```