# How to streaming mp4 artifact on Jenkins build page

Tags: html, jenkins, video-streaming, html5-video, jenkins-plugins

I want mp4 artifact file to be played if I click it.
[image]

However, when I click the mp4 artifact file, It looks like a picture below. It doesn't play
[image]

If I download it and then I can play it in my local PC.

So I tried HTML5 embed feature to streaming this. I tried two codes below, but, they didn't work.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="monkey_result_19.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/view/MonkeyTest/job/test22/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/monkey_result_19.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

For an MP4 file located in our build artifacts I was able to enable the video by adding `media-src 'self';` in addition to the default CSP options.

### Testing the change

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; media-src 'self';")
```

### To apply the change at startup

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; media-src 'self';" -jar jenkins.war
```

For more information about the Jenkins Content Security Policy, see the [Jenkins Docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing security option.
For example,

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

You can refer to [Jenkins Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618892/jenkins-content-security-policy)