# Changing Content Security Policy in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, content-security-policy

Referring to this

[Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin - No CSS is displayed when report is viewed in Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783964/jenkins-html-publisher-plugin-no-css-is-displayed-when-report-is-viewed-in-j)

I want to see the effect of System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
permanently.
So can this be added in jenkins pipeline?

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618892/jenkins-content-security-policy)

Comment: -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
How to add this in jenkins code?

Comment: I mean i want to do it in jenkins code and not jenkins.xml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.