# Jenkins not returning content security policy header in response

Tags: jenkins, devops, content-security-policy

For security purposes i want to implement CSP (content security policy) header in my jenkins url which is https://jenkins.example.com  I use this script to change the CSP

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the Content Security Policy
CSP="sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"

# Add the CSP to the JAVA_OPTS
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"$CSP\""

# Create a backup of the original jenkins.service file
sudo cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service.bak

# Use 'systemctl edit' to create an override file for Jenkins service
# This is the recommended way to modify service files in systemd
echo -e "[Service]\nEnvironment=\"JAVA_OPTS=${JAVA_OPTS}\"" | sudo SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee systemctl edit jenkins

# Reload the systemd manager configuration
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

# Restart Jenkins to apply the changes
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

but the response form `curl -I -L https://jenkins.example.com` was like this

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 17:19:48 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
x-hudson-theme: default
referrer-policy: same-origin
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
set-cookie: JSESSIONID.xxxxxxxxxx=node08f7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.node0; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
x-hudson: 1.395
x-jenkins: 2.426.1
x-jenkins-session: xxxxxxx
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-instance-identity: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
server: Jetty(10.0.17)
```

Is it returning the content security header or jenkins by default does not return any header or how to make it return csp header ?

Answer (score 1):

First, your CSP value differs from the one in "[Jenkins: Configuring Content Security Policy](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/configuring-content-security-policy/)"

```bash
# official
sandbox allow-same-origin; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
# yours
sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

But that does not remove the actual issue, which is that the CSP header is not set at all.

Check how the `JAVA_OPTS` are being set in the `systemd` service file for Jenkins. There might be a problem with how the environment variable is being passed to the Jenkins service. So make sure the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable is correctly applied to the Jenkins service. You can do this by inspecting the running Jenkins process:

```bash
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

Look for the JAVA_OPTS in the command line of the Jenkins process.

And double-check the systemd service override for Jenkins is correctly set up. You can check the override file using:

```bash
sudo systemctl cat jenkins
```

Make sure there are no conflicting JAVA_OPTS being set elsewhere, such as in a Jenkins configuration file or another systemd override.

This assumes Jenkins 2.346.1 or more, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874025/6309)

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72098626/6309), an override (`/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf`) might be more effective:

```bash
cat <<-'EOF' > /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true \
    -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=\"default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';\""
EOF

# Restart Jenkins
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart jenkins
```

---

> I have tried this but got the same.

So your Jenkins instance is running with the specified `JAVA_OPTS`, including the CSP settings, but the CSP header is still not appearing in the HTTP response.

Consider and double-check:

- Make sure the CSP syntax in the JAVA_OPTS is correctly formatted. CSP directives should be separated by semicolons, and the entire policy should be enclosed in quotes.
- Some Jenkins plugins might interfere with the CSP header. Review installed plugins for any that might affect HTTP headers or security settings.
- If Jenkins is behind a reverse proxy (like Nginx or Apache), make sure it is not stripping or altering HTTP headers. Check the configuration of the reverse proxy for any rules related to headers.
- Clear any server-side cache that might be serving outdated responses.
- Sometimes, network devices or firewalls can alter HTTP headers. Verify if any such device in your network could be affecting the headers.
- Besides JAVA_OPTS, check other Jenkins configuration files for any settings that might override or affect CSP.
- Consider increasing the logging level in Jenkins to gather more detailed information about the server's behavior and response handling.

Comment: I have tried this but got the same `ps aux | grep jenkins
jenkins     3485  5.4 43.8 2669688 426856 ?      Ssl  08:51   0:53 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=default-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080`

Comment: #  curl -I -L https://jenkins.mysite.com/
HTTP/2 200 
date: Tue, 28 Nov 2023 09:01:01 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate
x-hudson-theme: default
referrer-policy: same-origin
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
set-cookie: JSESSIONID.6e62fa9f=node01jahr9ersn6u71a1522mcdwfxm39.node0; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
x-hudson: 1.395
x-jenkins: 2.426.1
x-jenkins-session: f6b2ade6
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-instance-identity: xxx
server: Jetty(10.0.17)

Comment: the jenkins version i am running is Jenkins 2.426.1

Comment: @Neetesshhr I have edited the answer to suggests some points for you to check.